# Why does Javascript RETURN incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

In Internet Explorer, my HTML code invokes a JavaScript function which changes an icon image and returns to the originating code (PHP with embedded HTML). It works absolutely fine. In Firefox, the identical code doesn't return correctly. It appears to return to the PHP module entry point, versus just returning to the window. Since I originally called the PHP code with a parameter, when the Javascript returns to the original PHP entry point, no parameter is present and the code logically fails.

Comment: Can we see a sample of code than can reproduce this issue? (we don't need to see all of it!) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser-compatibility is always a problem when developing javascript. Try to use some well-known js libs , for example jquery, to ease  your development.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that JavaScript apparently defaults the HTML form to a POST SUBMIT (rather unusual) and Internet Explorer does not. So, I added onsubmit="return false" to the form and all works well.